# Como reproduzir uma lista que pule os números de acordo com o número digitado

Tags: python-3.x

De preferência algo que explique a resposta abaixo(sem os espaços)

0

1

4

9

16

Comment: Isso corresponde à serie n², facil de fazer em python com o operador `**` de exponenciação

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar compreensão de listas para essa questão, muito mais idiomático:

```
[ i**2 for i in range(5) ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Se você quer algo que gere este resultado que você mostrou na pergunta, só fazer isso:

```
i = 0
lista=[]

while i < 5:
   lista.append((i ** 2)) 
   i += 1
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

e assim por diante.

Comment: Mas e para terminar no 16?

Comment: @LucasSouza fiz a alteração na resposta, olhe la